# recursive anonymous function to calculate series sum

Tags: perl, recursion, anonymous-function

I tried to write a function to compute following,
[image]

all I could come up with was this, which does not work.

```
$fact = sub {
    $n = shift;
    if($n==0 || $n ==1){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return $n*&$fact($n-1);
    }
}

sub fun{
    ($x,$n)= @_;
    if($n==0){
        return 1;
    }elsif($n == 1){
        return $x;
    }else{
        return ($x)/&$fact($n)+fun($x,$n-1);
    }
}



print (fun(3,5));
```

Comment: You're mixing up your two functions.  The sub `fact` only takes a single number *n*, and returns *n*!. You need to define a separate function that *uses* `fact` to compute the original sum, and call that.

Comment: Also, if you are really supposed to make a function that is both anonymous and recursive, you will need to use some sort of zero-point combinator.

Comment: @Mark Reed, It's far easier to just temporarily create a name for the recursive sub when it's being executed: `sub { local *_r = sub { ... _r(...) ... }; _r(@_) }`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, always use

```
use strict;
use warnings qw( all );
```

It would have caught one of your errors.

---

Secondly, you misnamed your sub, you missed a `my`, and you invented a special case (since `($x**1)/1! == $x`)<sup>[1]</sup>. Ignoring the need to make it anonymous for now, `f` is simply:

```
sub f {
   my ($x, $n) = @_;
   return 1 if $n == 0;
   return ($x**$n) / fact($x) + f($x, $n-1);
}
```

Similarly, `fact` is simply:

```
sub fact {
   my ($n) = @_;
   my $acc = 1;
   $acc *= $_ for 1..$n;
   return $acc;
}
```

---

On to the question, making a recursive function anonymous is just a question of replacing the recursive calls with `__SUB__->(...)`<sup>[2]</sup>, so the following is the anonymous version:

```
use feature qw( current_sub );

my $f = sub {
   my ($x, $n) = @_;
   return 1 if $n == 0;
   return ($x**$n) / fact($x) + __SUB__->($x, $n-1);
};
```

And if you wanted `fact` to be anonymous too,

```
use feature qw( current_sub );

my $f = sub {
   my ($x, $n) = @_;
   return 1 if $n == 0;

   my $fact = sub {
      my ($n) = @_;
      my $acc = 1;
      $acc *= $_ for 1..$n;
      return $acc;
   };

   return ($x**$n) / $fact->($x) + __SUB__->($x, $n-1);
};
```

---

That said, using recursion is a *huge* waste for this function. Here's an efficient implementation:

```
my $f = sub {
   my ($x, $n) = @_;

   my $acc             = 1;
   my $numerator_acc   = 1;
   my $denominator_acc = 1;
   for (1..$n) {
      $numerator_acc   *= $x;
      $denominator_acc *= $_;
      $acc += ( $numerator_acc / $denominator_acc );
   }

   return $acc;
};
```

---

1. Technically, you invented two since `($x**0)/0! == 1`, but `$n == 0` has to be treated specially to some extent no matter what.
2. `__SUB__` was introduced in Perl 5.16. It was more complicated before that if you wanted to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Wow ! awesome. You are a genius. !

Comment: __SUB__->($x, $n-1) , can you explain about this part. or add link to a tutorial to know this ?

Comment: [`__SUB__`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/__SUB__.html) returns a reference to the currently executing sub.

Comment: And `->()` is how you call a subroutine through a reference; you would need to call `$f->(3,5)` to use ikegami's implementation with your sample inputs, for example.